# Why Autoit script doesn't run over SSH (W10)?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, autoit

a simple command on AutoIT:

```
ControlClick("Sighthound Video","","[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:46]","Primary")
ControlClick("Sighthound Video","","[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:49]","Primary")
```

to click a button in an application.
I create a script called "Toggle.au3".

If I click double click, it works.
If I launch it from the command line, it works.
If I launch from a remote computer with Putty (through SSH) it doesn't works; no error appears but doesn't perform the tasks.

Why? I have also tried to compile in a exe file, but nothing changes.

- Windows 10
- Bitvise SSH Server
- AutoIT 3.3.14.2

THX.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't have rights from a remote computer.
If the au3.exe gets the remote's privilege then it is definitely not going to interact.

Edit: However ALL autoit commands are windows based commands, which means C++ commands. If you can call those commands through putty or CMD then it might work